# Restore In-App-Purchase (Using Parse)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, in-app-purchase

I added an option to buy an In-App-Purchase into my app. I do this using Parse. 
Here's my code to complete a purchase:

```
        PFPurchase.buyProduct("Name.App.RemoveAds", block: { (error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            println("Error occured: \(error)")
        }

        else {

        }
    })
```

My app got rejected by apple because ther's no restore purchase button which can be used to restore the purchase after an app update.
Now I'd like to ask you how I can restore an In-App-Purchase (with or without Parse - should work both or?).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `PFPurchase.restore()`.

[Here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFPurchase.html) you can find the PFPurchase documentation.

This will trigger the observer that you need to add for the product.

```
PFPurchase.addObserverForProduct("Name.App.RemoveAds", block: { (transaction : SKPaymentTransaction!) -> Void in
        ...  
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Ok I added PFPurchase.restore() into my function. But it's not working. Don`t know why.

Comment: Do you know what I have to change/edit? I really need your help.

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial](https://daweihai.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/fast-in-app-purchase-and-restore-with-parse/), it might help.

Comment: I saw it already but it doesn't bring me further. Could you please help me? Do I have to add some more code? I added the observer in the `appDelegate` so this couldn't be the reason. I don't know what I can do anymore. Read all tutorials in the web but nothing brings me further.

Comment: I debugged, yes but the app isn't crashing it just happens nothing.

Comment: Ok, I got an Idea how to do the restore. Could you please help me with this (verry simple problem but I didn't get it) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143193/present-alert-view-in-main-view-controller-called-from-subclass/34143405#34143405