# present alert view in main view controller (called from subclass)

Tags: ios, swift, view, uialertview, viewcontroller

I have tow views in my app. A main view(ViewController.swift) and a sidebar(SideBar.swift). If I tapp a button in the sidebar an `UIAlertView`should be displayed (I call a function in ViewController.swift). But the app crashes because the main view is nil. Do you know how I can fix this?

My code in the function (display alert):

```
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "You need to log in first", message: "To access the special features of the app you need to log in first.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: .Default, handler: { (alertAction) -> Void in
    }))
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Crash log:

```
0x724160 <+60>:  bl     0x75961c                  ; function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
->  0x724164 <+64>:  trap
```

Comment: Do you have reference to ViewController.swift in sidebar class?

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions that come to my mind.

1. Declare a protocol and use the delegate to pass on the alert call to the MainView.

First, define a protocol in our SideBar.swift (Lets call it AlertDelegate).

```
 protocol AlertDelegate {

    func alertMain()

}
```

Now we create a delegate variable in SideBar.swift.

```
var alertDelegate:AlertDelegate?
```

Then we make our MainView (ViewController.swift) adhere to the AlertDelegate protocol.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,foo,bar,AlertDelegate
```

And add in the function for the AlertDelegate protocol. Here is where you would put your UIAlertController code.

```
func alertMain(){

 //Present UIAlertController
}
```

Finally, we have to set out ViewController to the delegate *alertDelegate*

2. Present your UIAlertController using AppDelegate KeyWindow. I probably wouldn't recommend this method, but this is how you would do it.

   ```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Can you give me an example how I can do this? I'm still learning Swift.

Comment: Swift 4: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)